# iOS8 - Simulator - How to get Locations simulated

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode6

My App tracks your location.
With iOS8 I had to change how it was starting location services.
I got this working with

```
[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
```

and adding NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription to the plist file.

The app now gets your location when run on a device, but not in the simulator.

Any clues on how to get this to work in the simulator? It used to!!!

Comment: I decided to post this in case anyone else had the same issue. I got the simulator to respond to location changes again by adding NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription back into the plist file. I had removed it since my app needs the Always permission instead of WhenInUse. By adding this back to the plist the simulator is now happy. I did not have this issue on the physical device, just the simulator.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and mark your own answer as correct. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to post this in case anyone else had the same issue. I got the simulator to respond to location changes again by adding NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription back into the plist file. I had removed it since my app needs the Always permission instead of WhenInUse. By adding this back to the plist the simulator is now happy. I did not have this issue on the physical device, just the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

In the iOS Simulator, select Debug > Location, then choose your location.

Comment: Yes, this exactly how I did it prior to iOS 8 and what had stopped working.